# Maclaurin series for $ f(f(z)) = \exp(z) - \exp(-z) + \exp(-z/2) - \exp(-z/5)+ \exp(-z/6) - \exp(-z/9)$

Tags: taylor-expansion, functional-equations, complex-dynamics

I wonder about the Maclaurin series of the analytic $f(z)$ such that

$$ f(f(z)) = g(z) = \exp(z) - \exp(-z) + \exp(-z/2) - \exp(-z/5)+ \exp(-z/6) - \exp(-z/9) $$

Since zero is a fixpoint and $g'(0) = \frac{74}{45} > 1$ we can find such a Maclaurin series of $f(z)$ in many ways.

Using Koenigs function for instance.
Or by using Carleman matrices.

We then can compute

$$f(z) = a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 + ...$$

I would like many terms of these coefficients and I wonder how many terms we need before one of them is negative ?

I also wonder about the exact radius of $f(z)$.
Ofcourse the radius is equal or less than the distance to the next fixpoint of $g(z)$.

I know there is a fixpoint for $g$ around $-0.218 + 1.504 i$ and its complex conjugate.

Is the radius equal to the closest distance to a point $A$ where $f(f(A))=g(A)$ still holds ?

Comment: The period of $g(z)$ is $180 \pi i $ btw. Just in case you were wondering.

Comment: Can't we take $a_1=-\sqrt{\frac{74}{45}}$ for simplicity?

Comment: Why this particular $g(x)$, mick?

Comment: @BobDobbs: I think the minus sign was a typo ? Taking that square root is correct. The higher terms are the harder part. Oh you thought I wanted negative as fast as possible I assume. HMM not sure if $a_1$ is negative we have non-zero radius ... I need to think

Comment: @GerryMyerson because it is a very good asymptotic to $\exp(x)$ We can then use it to do tetration by infinite composition. 
The half-iterate of the exponential is ln ln ln ...( g( exp exp exp ...
If the derivatives are all positive that would be interesting although we enter deep conjectures of tetration research what is beyond here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson here are some links , but the claims might not be correct. Just to get an idea of how the idea works : 

https://sites.google.com/site/tommy1729/tetration

https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=424

Those are old webpages so more historical in a way ...

Comment: It's $e^x$ minus a bunch of stuff that goes to zero with $x$. But so is $e^x-e^{-x/17}$, or $e^x+e^{-x/42}-e^{-x/1729}$, or ..., so I still don't see why this particular $g(x)$ should interest anyone.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That is a bit off-topic but ok. 
Your third example does not even have 0 as a fixpoint.
Secondly the +/- patterns ensures that we have a fixpoint at $0$ and that we are getting better and better corrections.
Also jumping to $1729$ is way to fast. We want to get close to exp AND we want positive taylor coefficients.
Also we want an entire function approximating $\exp(x)$ very good. 
And we want the taylor coefficients to be rational numbers for simplicity.
Also we want to function not to grow to fast for negative $x$ or complex $z$.
They are fairly restrictive conditions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ofcourse my function is a truncated version of this one by my mentor at the tetration forum : https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1728

I also want to point out we want to get close to $\exp(x)$ but still have the first and second derivative of the approximation strictly positive for positive real $x$.

So $\exp(x) - \exp(-10 x^2)$ is not a good approximation.
Also note the closed form for the first derivative.

Comment: OK, so, there are lots and lots of reasons for being interested in that particular $g(x)$ – and all of that should have been in the body of your question, instead of making me pull teeth to get the information out of you in the comments. Please edit your question to indicate why you are interested in this particular $g$, as that will make it a much better question. It's not off-topic, not in the slightest; it's the most important part of the topic, it's the motivation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But in essence it is just a taylor series of a half-iterate and the tag complex dynamics is there.
I do not want to scare people away by mentioning tetration or other stuff they never heard of. It is standard math the way it is formulated now. I recently got accused of writing to much " useless context " in my question.

Comment: I can't speak to the accusation you got on another occasion, but the context you have given in these comments is far from useless, it's vital, and most of it makes no mention of tetration or anything else people here may not have heard of (I've never heard of Koenig's function, nor of Carleman matrices, but I have heard of tetration, for what it's worth).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix